2 Samuel 12:17, ברא translated as 'eat', is it incorrect?
ויקמו זקני ביתו עליו להקימו מן־הארץ ולא אבה ולא־ברא אתם לחם
http://biblehub.com/interlinear/2_samuel/12-17.htm

And the elders of his house stood beside him, to raise him from the
ground, but he would not, nor did he eat food with them. ESV

Many translations translated לחם as 'food', others translate 'eat anything with them'.
https://biblehub.com/2_samuel/12-17.htm
Some do indeed translate לחם as bread, but all of them translate ברא as 'eat'.
Is it incorrectly translated?

Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question and joining our group.

וְ     and/nor

לֹֽא    no/did not

בָרָ֥א   he eat

אִתָּ֖ם   with them

לָֽחֶם   bread/food

(BHS2003)


ברה: = II ברא; ... to consume food with somebody 2S 12:17; —2. בָּ׳ מִיַּד to receive a diet from someone, when ill 2S 13:6, 10 (|| אכל verse 5). ...
--
Koehler, L., Baumgartner, W., Richardson, M. E. J., & Stamm, J. J. (1994–2000). In The Hebrew and Aramaic lexicon of the Old Testament (electronic ed., p. 154). E.J. Brill.

You are probably confusing this word with a well known homonym.

I  ברי   ... : ברא      to create; ... in the OT I ברא is a specifically theological term, the subject of which is invariably God; ...
--
Ibid., (electronic ed., p. 153)

While לֶחֶם primarily means bed.  It was also used for food, as the fourth meaning in the referenced lexicon.

I לֶחֶם (...): ...
—4. food, nourishment
-- Ibid., (electronic ed., p. 526)


Oh thank you, I didn't know what a homonym is.
